# Angular 16 enableIndexedDbPersistence

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angularfire, angularfire2-offline

I've managed to get @angular/fire working in an Angular standalone app, but I'm attempting to turn on the offline capabilities like I have in the past, and I'm now seeing that `enableIndexedDbPersistence` has been marked as deprecated.  It suggests the following:

This function will be removed in a future major release. Instead, set FirestoreSettings.cache to an instance of IndexedDbLocalCache to turn on IndexedDb cache. Calling this function when FirestoreSettings.cache is already specified will throw an exception.

I've gone to the documentation that usually translates very well to how @angular/fire is used (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline), but I don't see any obvious direction on what to do.  The docs show the use of an options argument being passed into the call to `initializeFirestore`, but Angular apps don't seem to use this method externally (from the developer's perspective).

what I currently have is the following:

```js
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideServiceWorker('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: !isDevMode(),
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000',
    }),
    importProvidersFrom(
      provideFirebaseApp(() => 
        initializeApp({
          // ... my info
        })
      ),
      provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
      provideFirestore(() => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        enableIndexedDbPersistence(firestore); // Marked as deprecated :(
        return firestore;
      }),
      provideStorage(() => getStorage())
    ),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured this out, finally, just before submitting my question.  I took a closer look at how the `provideFirebaseApp` factory function provided the app, and it was calling `initializeApp`.  So for the `provideFirestore` factory function, I figured maybe I COULD actually follow the documentation mentioned in my question if instead of using `getFirestore()`, I use the `initializeFirestore(...)` method, both of which return an instance of `Firestore`.  Works like a charm if you do the following:

```js
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    ...
    importProvidersFrom(
      ...
      provideFirestore(() => 
        initializeFirestore(getApp(), {
          localCache: persistentLocalCache({
            tabManager: persistentMultipleTabManager(),
          }),
        })
      ),
      ...
    ),
  ],
};
}
```

Comment: Where are you using `appConfig`? I tried to use `provideFirestore` inside `AppModule` `imports` and `providers`, but neither worked. I can read from server but not from cache.

Comment: I'm using `appConfig` in the main.ts file where the application is bootstrapped.  It is the second parameter in the call to `bootstrapApplication`, after using `AppComponent` for the first argument.  This angular application was built with the `--standalone` flag.

Comment: thanks, these dirty hacks make angularfire suck a pain in the ass to use